# Getting “Front controller reached 100 router match iterations” error in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, exception

I am getting this error message, both on frontend and adminpanel. The error is from: `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php`

This is the function where the error is thrown:

```
public function init()
    {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_front_init_before', array('front'=>$this));
        $routersInfo = Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(self::XML_STORE_ROUTERS_PATH);
......
```

This `self::XML_STORE_ROUTERS_PATH` is null and `$routersInfo` too . Any idea why ?

Comment: On first glance this seems to be a duplicate, Have you read this article ? https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug#the-fix and please take a look at https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug#update-2-further-improvements do let me know if its not your exact issue and I would be glad to provide a helping hand :)

Comment: srry but that didn't work out for me . I tried it :)

Comment: $routersInfo is null ,that's why I m getting this error.

Comment: Have you changed anything? Maybe cache isnt valid, try to flush. Or read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262129/magento-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations-error/33684913#33684913

Comment: The content of var/cache is empty .

Comment: I had to clean up the cache from redis : `redis-cli flushall` and that fixed the problem. Thnx for the answers

Comment: Dude add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to clean up my REDIS cache by executing this command:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

Thank you all for your support

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be missing some config files or they may have incorrect permissions, could you run the following code and paste your output.

```
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app();
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
 $routersInfo = Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig('web/routers');
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($routersInfo);
 echo "</pre>"
```

essentially router info should return the config values at 'web/routers'

As an additional precaution make sure that compilation is turned off and your cache is flushed.

Comment: I have the same issue as OP. Clearing cache does fix the issue, but I'd like the issue to not happen in the first place so I don't suffer the downtime. When I run that, `$routersInfo` is `NULL`. Any more insight on where to look to figure out why it's caching some empty value for web/routers?

Comment: This could be a reason, https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug web/routers should be generated from the config files

Comment: Have been reading that, but have been unable to get what he's done there to work for me, even the debugging steps. If I find a solution that works for me I'll be sure to post it.

Comment: What happens is something goes wrong while loading the cache with Mage_Core_Model_Config::init() and causes a corrupt cache to be saved which the author describes how he fixes it at the save function.

Comment: I understand that, however his fix isn't working for me.

Comment: are you using any specific cache backend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68814/discussion-between-goose-and-nathanielr).